# Set Default in a FieldEditorPreferencePage via ScopedPreferenceStore

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Good evening,

With java 1.7 I am trying to override the `performApply()` method for a FieldEditorPreferencePage using code similar to the snippet below. (the additional code doesn't make a difference, just this one method)

```
@Override
public void performApply() {
    scopedPreferenceStore.setDefault(PREF_KEY, value);
    super.performApply();
}
```

Essentially I want to update the default preference value for `PREF_KEY` so when the user hits Restore Defaults after applying a change, it uses the new value and not the old one.

The issue is that if I do this, when I rerun my program the new default isn't stored. If I forgo the use of `setDefault()`, the new default is stored.

To further clarify

With using `setDefault`:

If I change preference A to 100, click apply, change preference A to 25, then click restore defaults, I will see 100. If I restart my program and look at preference A I see 50.

Without using set default:

If I change preference A to 100, click apply, then click restore defaults, I will see 50. But if I change it back to 100, click apply, then restart my program and look at preference A I see 100.

What is causing this behavior and how I can I get around it?

Note: I am using a preference initializer, however I wish to dynamically change the default to the last applied user input, without the weird behavior mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

To set preference defaults you should use the `initializer` element of the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.preferences` extension point to define a 'preferences initializer' class. Don't try and override this in a field editor or anywhere else.

```java
 <extension point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.preferences">
   <initializer class="com.example.MyPreferenceInitializer"/>
 </extension>
```

```java
public class MyPreferenceInitializer extends AbstractPreferenceInitializer
{
  @Override
  public void initializeDefaultPreferences()
  {
    IPreferenceStore prefs = Activator.getDefault().getPreferenceStore();

    prefs.setDefault(PREF_KEY, VALUE); 
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to change the default dynamically after initialization

Comment: You can't change a default dynamically. Default values aren't stored anywhere and  the next time you restart it will revert back to the preference initializer value.